# Appcelerator. Change image in image view on click

Tags: imageview, appcelerator-mobile

Titanium SDK version: 1.7.0
iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I am developing an iOS app and I got an image that acts like a button in a row in a table and when I click this image view I want to change the image to another image.

For example if I click the image view which displays picture1.png I want it to show picture2.png after the click.

How can I do this?

I tried e.source.image = "picture2.png"; but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using:

```
e.source.image = '../images/picture2.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove your Ti.UI.SIZE in TableView and TableViewRow both height and width... It will work